# how to include a library in a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, html

In other to separate the `HTML` pages from the `JavaScript` implementation, I created different `.js` files for every set of functionalities on my website. 
If I were going to implement `JavaScript` from a `HTML` page, I would do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/javascript/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
```

However, how would I go over including that library, `jquery.qtip.js` into a `.js` file, like 
`heatmap.js`?
I'm asking that because I'm getting the following error from firebug:

```
TypeError: $("mytable td").qtip is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

style : 'ui-tooltip-tipsy ui-tooltip-shadow'
```

If I were in java, I would include an external library or class as:

```
import java.util.*
```

Is there a similar way in JavaScript?

```
function heatmap()
{
    var input = document.getElementById("heatmap").value;

    // TAKE THE HEATMAP HTML OBJECT AND MAKE A POST TO THE BACKEND
    $("#heatmap").empty().html(baseurl + "/images/loader.gif/>");
    $.post(baseurl + "index.php/heatmap/getMatrix",
        {
            input : input.toString()
        },

        function(answer){
            var list = eval('(' + answer + ')');
            var temp = list.split(" ");
            makeTable(temp);

            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('mytable td').qtip({
                overwrite : false,      // make sure it can' be overwritten
                content : {
                    text : function(api){
                    var msg = "Interaction: " + $(this).html(); 
                    return msg;
                    }
                },
                position : {
                   my : 'top left',
                   target : 'mouse',
                   viewport : $(window),    // keep it on screen at all time is possible
                   adjust : {
                    x : 10, y : 10
                   }
                },

                hide : {
                   fixed  : true        // helps to prevent the tooltip
                },
                style : 'ui-tooltip-tipsy ui-tooltip-shadow' 
                });
            });
        });

}
```

**************** ADDING MAKETABLE FUNCTION ***********************

```
function makeTable(data)
{
    var row = new Array();
    var cell = new Array();

    var row_num = 18;
    var cell_num = 16;

    var tab = document.createElement('table');
    tab.setAttribute('id', 'mytable');
    tab.border = '1px';

    var tbo = document.createElement('tbody');

    for(var i = 0; i < row_num; i++){
            row[i] = document.createElement('tr');

            var upper = (i+1)*16;
            var lower = i*16;
            for(var j = lower; j < upper; j++){
                cell[j] = document.createElement('td');
                //cell[j].setAttribute('class', 'selector');
                if(data[j] != undefined){
                    var index = Math.round(parseFloat(data[j])*100) / 100;
                    var count = document.createTextNode(index);
                    cell[j].appendChild(count);

                    /* specify which color better suits the heatmap */
                    if(index <= -4){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
                    }
                    else if(index > -4 && index <= -3.5){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FF2200";
                    }
                    else if(index > -3.5 && index <= -3.0){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FF2222";
                    }
                    else if(index >= -3.0 && index < -2.5){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FF3311";
                    }
                    else if(index >= -2.5 && index < -2.0){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FF5500";
                    }
                    else if(index >= -2.0 && index < -1.5){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FF8811";
                    }
                    else if(index >= -1.5 && index < -1.0){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FFAA22";
                    }
                    else if(index >= -1.0 && index < -0.5){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FFCC11";
                    }
                    else if(index >= -0.5 && index < 0){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FFCC00";
                    }
                    else if(index == 0){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
                    }
                    else if(index > 0 && index < 0.5){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FF8800";
                    }
                    else if(index >= 0.5 && index < 1.0){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FFBB00";
                    }
                    else if(index >= 1.0 && index < 1.5){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00";
                    }
                    else if(index >= 1.5 && index < 2.0){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#00CC00";
                    }
                    else if(index >= 2.0 && index < 2.5){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#008800";
                    }
                    else if(index >= 2.5 && index < 3.0){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#006600";
                    }
                    else if(index >= 3.0 && index < 3.5){
                        cell[j].style.backgroundColor = "#004400";
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                    row[i].appendChild(cell[j]);
                }
            }

            tbo.appendChild(row[i]);
        }

        tab.appendChild(tbo);
        document.getElementById('mytable').appendChild(tab);
}
```

Comment: Is copying the whole source and pasting it inside your `.js` a viable option? Otherwise, you may be looking for [require.js](http://requirejs.org/).

Comment: Because you mentioned Java and you seem to place value on organization, I think @FabrícioMatté is right: you'd probably like require.js.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a script loader like http://requirejs.org/

```
require(["jquery", "jquery.qtip.js", ...], function($) {
    // do something when loaded
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to include `.js` files with `script` tags, so you have 3 options:

- The aforementioned `script` tag;
- Compressing both files' source in a single file;
- Using a modular loader such as [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

There's no simple built-in function to halt the execution of the script while you load another script's source in JavaScript such as PHP's `include`/`require` or Java's `import` or C's `include`, because JavaScript's script loading is asynchronous -- the scripts execute in the order you include them in the page, but they won't wait to load a dynamically added script.

Note that the first and third options make extra HTTP requests, so if your script always requires such a function, you may include it in your script itself to reduce HTTP requests. Still, if you want to keep your `.js` files split and import them from another `.js` file, your best option is [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Also, if you were using jQuery, you could use [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) and run the rest of your code inside `$.getScript`'s callback.

---

Since you're using jQuery, here's a jQuery-only solution for adding the qtip `.js` dynamically when needed and supplying :

```
if (!$().qtip) //if qtip is not included/loaded into the page yet
    $.getScript('http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/packages/latest/jquery.qtip.min.js', heatmap);
else heatmap();
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/EWjFJ/3/)**

Of course, you can just use the `$.getScript` directly inside the DOM ready event or anywhere in the page as well:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getScript('http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/packages/latest/jquery.qtip.min.js');
});
```

Beware that `$.getScript` will be asynchronous, so you have to wrap the rest of the code which depends on this script inside its callback. There are ways to set this as a synchronous ajax call, but it could freeze up/slow down the loading of your page, hence forcing it to be synchronous is unrecommended.

RequireJS is a better option if you need to include many `.js` files.

Comment: If you look into the function `heatmap`, there is a call to `makeTable(temp);`: It creates a HTML dynamically using JavaScript, however, when I do a `$("mytable td")` it's empty, so it means `qtip` is being loaded correctly.

Comment: Where's the `makeTable` function defined or what is it supposed to do? Are you sure it's appending a table to the DOM?

Comment: I'm not appending that to the `DOM`. I also updated my question to include the `makeTable` function.

Comment: in the `HTML` I have this : `<div id="mytable"></div>`

Comment: I'm taking a look. `tab.setAttribute('id', 'mytable');` then `document.getElementById('mytable').appendChild(tab);`, seems like you have duplicate IDs then which would generate errors when you get your `qtip` to work.

Comment: Should I give them different names?

Comment: `TypeError: document.getElementById("test1") is null`
This was after I changed the IDs

Comment: Did you change your html `div`'s id to `test1` as well? Oh and are you using qtip2 or qtip1.4?

Comment: `qtip2` ... and the table is being created, however `$("mytable td") = []`

Comment: Are you sure your `$.post` is returning what you expect? I'm making a jsfiddle to illustrate it atm.

Comment: The problem was `$("mytable td")` instead of `$("#mytable td")`. However, I'm still getting the same problem

Comment: Did you manage to solve it then? Woah I had to read your comment 3 times to notice it. Always overlooking the small details.

Comment: So, the table is being created with `td`s? The problem is that you can't get the qtip to work or with the table still?

Comment: The table works fine. `$(#mytable td)` returns me all the `td` elements of the table. However, I can't get `qtip` to work. Do you have an idea why not?

Comment: Yup, you probably didn't include the qtip library correctly. Take a second read at my answer now, there's 3-4 ways to do it. I'm working on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EWjFJ/) which currently doesn't have a tooltip, so I'll try to include it with jQuery-only now.

Comment: Check my last update, it should suffice for the qtip issue. `:)`